# How to populate fields of column in pivot table in Java using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created Pivot table in Excel using Java POI class functions :
below is the code

```
XSSFSheet pivot = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

       AreaReference source = new AreaReference(pivot.getSheetName()+"!A$1:P$"+String.valueOf(pivot.getLastRowNum()+1));

       CellReference position = new CellReference("B3");
       XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = Pivot.createPivotTable(source, position, pivot);

       pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);

       //insert column

       pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 1, "Column1");
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wshr.jpg) contains the data fields of the pivot, using this above code, i am able to populate filters, values, rows. But for column part I am unable to populate the field. The addColumnLabel method is not working here. I need to add same "Type" field in "column" as well as "value" field of pivot table.

Comment: No its not appropriate, i have inserted the image, you can get to know my problem, addColumnLabel with dataConsolidateMethod is not working for me.
I need to populate the column field after creation of column label.

Comment: Can anyone please provide me a proper solution for it.

Comment: I tested the addColumnLabel(...) and it works for me. I get a column with label as **Column1**. You say that addColumnLabel(..) is not working for you but, then you say in the comment that you need to populate colum field after creation of column label. Can you update your question to include the code where you try to populate column fields? Also if possible, attach a screenshot of the Pivote table that you want as well the data that you are using.